# Create external dependencies and add it to other project with gradle

Tags: gradle

I have two spring boot projet

A and B

would like to create a new projet to put common thing there

A
B

commons

how to add commons to A and B like a external dependencies?

Comment: maybe, you can simply generate a artifact from commons and push to nexus, then pull the dependency to A and B.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your project layout as below:

```
project
|- common
|- proja
|- projb
```

1. you need `settings.gradle`

   ```
   rootProject.name = 'project'
   include 'common'
   include 'proja'
   include 'projb'
   ```
2. then you need to update your build.gradle under `project` like this:

   ```
   plugins {
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.4.RELEASE'
   }

   subprojects { // common configurations for all subprojects
       apply plugin: 'groovy'
       apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }

       dependencies { // common dependencies for all subprojects
           compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10'

           testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
           testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4'
       }
   }

   project ("proja") {
       dependencies { // proja-specific dependencies
           compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
           compile project(":common")
       }

   }

   project ("projb") {
       dependencies { // projb-specific dependencies

           compile project(":common")
       }
   }
   ```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: i said external... don't have a root

Comment: @roberttrudel Are you thinking of composite build, git-subdmoules?

Comment: check solutions i provided

Answer (score 0):

external solution seem the way to go

my commons build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.0.M2'
}

distributions {
    main{
        baseName = 'commons-code'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-parameters"]
}
```

In my main project

i have an build.gradle

in the dependencies section i have

```
compile project (':commons-code')
```

and in the settings.gradle file i have

```
include ":commons-code"
project(":commons-code").projectDir = file("/home/bob/dev/project/commons/")
```

Comment: I think the major difference is you use the absolute file path instead of the relative one? Correct me if I am wrong.